# Set up svnperms pre-commit hook

Tags: python, svn, unix, pre-commit

I'm trying to implement svnperms into a repository, but am having difficulty with a few things:

pre-commit has the execute permissions:

```
-rwxrwxr-x   1 svnadm     svn           3018 May 27 10:11 pre-commit
```

This is my call to svnperms within pre-commit:

```
# Check that the author of this commit has the rights to perform
# the commit on the files and directories being modified.
SVNPERMS=/usr/local/svn/scripts/svnperms.py
$SVNPERMS -r $REPOS -t $TXN || exit 1
```

I've got svnperms.py installed in the location specified:

```
# ls -l /usr/local/svn/scripts
total 24
-rwxrwxr-x   1 svnadm     svn          11840 May 25 07:48 svnperms.py
```

svnperms.py is in UNIX format - no ^M line endings.

TortoiseSVN comes back with:

```
Command: Commit  
Modified: C:\projects\Sandbox\Trunk\Test.txt  
Sending content: C:\projects\Sandbox\Trunk\Test.txt  
Error: Commit failed (details follow):  
Error: 'pre-commit' hook failed with error output:  
Error: No such file or directory: python
```

Calling svnperms with no paramters shows:

```
/usr/local/svn/scripts/svnperms.py
missing required option(s): repository, either transaction or a revision
Usage: svnperms.py OPTIONS

Options:
    -r PATH    Use repository at PATH to check transactions
    -t TXN     Query transaction TXN for commit information
    -f PATH    Use PATH as configuration file (default is repository
               path + /conf/svnperms.conf)
    -s NAME    Use section NAME as permission section (default is
               repository name, extracted from repository path)
    -R REV     Query revision REV for commit information (for tests)
    -A AUTHOR  Check commit as if AUTHOR had commited it (for tests)
    -h         Show this message
```

The UNIX admin has recently installed python, but wasn't sure if all the dependencies are there.  If that's the issue, I'm not sure how to determine that, since python seems to be working based on the output above.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My guess is that the location of the `python` binary is not in `$PATH` for the svn server. The  shabang line of `svnperms.py` reads:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

But that assumes that the executable lies in the `$PATH` of the caller. If you don't have permissions to modify the runtime environment of your subversion server, try replacing `python` in the shabang line with the path given by `which python` when you run it interactively.

Comment: Thanks! That did it!
Looking more at the notes, apparently it's a common problem for the script to not inherit $PATH.

Comment: According to http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.reposadmin.create.html#svn.reposadmin.create.hookshook programs are executed with an empty environment by design for security purposes.