# How to modify commit message in pre-commit hook?

Tags: svn

> [Server side hook scripts](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-repository-hooks.html)
>   [Set up svnperms pre-commit hook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/916758/set-up-svnperms-pre-commit-hook)
>   [Use the commit message in a CVS pre-commit hook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1857101/use-the-commit-message-in-a-cvs-pre-commit-hook)

I am in the process of refactoring a project by extracting several libraries from it. The libraries are moved to different repositories and are checked out via `svn:external`.

The problem is that commits to the central repository can't any longer explain the state of the system at the time of the commit. Initially, I am solving this problem by appending a line to each commit `Tested with libA:revXXXX, libB:revYYYY, libZ:revZZZZ.` by hand. Naturally, this will be unacceptable once my colleagues join in on the project, plus the libraries start being used on new projects.

What is the correct way to automate this i.e. *on each commit, check latest version of `trunk` on all `svn:extern` dependencies and append that information to the commit message*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should NOT do this in a pre-commit hook, if it is even possible. The [SVN book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.reposadmin.create.html) says:

> While hook scripts can do almost anything, there is one dimension in
>   which hook script authors should show restraint: do not modify a
>   commit transaction using hook scripts. While it might be tempting to
>   use hook scripts to automatically correct errors, shortcomings, or
>   policy violations present in the files being committed, doing so can
>   cause problems. Subversion keeps client-side caches of certain bits of
>   repository data, and if you change a commit transaction in this way,
>   those caches become indetectably stale. This inconsistency can lead to
>   surprising and unexpected behavior. Instead of modifying the
>   transaction, you should simply validate the transaction in the
>   pre-commit hook and reject the commit if it does not meet the desired
>   requirements. As a bonus, your users will learn the value of careful,
>   compliance-minded work habits.

If you don't want to include your commit comment by hand, you could always write a script that wraps svn commit and make everyone use it.

But...why do you need this in your commit message at all? You're using svn:externals, which when used properly, will already document the versions used. You *are* using them properly, with explicit revisions, aren't you?

Comment: It shows how inept I am. The root folder of my project has a property `svn:externals` that contains several lines of the sort of `http://192.168.10.2/svn/main/CodeTemplates CodeTemplates`. What revisions? Those libraries are supposed to be constantly evolving.

Comment: Change it to something like `http://192.168.10.2/svn/main/CodeTemplates@1234 CodeTemplates` to pull in the specific revision 1234 of the CodeTemplates library. Why do this? First, when you update to old versions of your project, you see the *entire* project exactly as it existed at that time, including the externals. Second, if library development is independent of the main project, you can control *when* to pull in potentially breaking changes. See the [section on externals in the svn book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.externals.html) for details and a big warning box.

Comment: This approach is very inconvenient as of now - because the project is like a wrapper around the library - all the development is happening inside the library - but seems to be the only sane solution. Once things stabilize, I'll apply it. (+1 and accept)